# about complicated RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regexp to check the String "incould `\w,-,.` and not start with ."
I hope the result is

> abc  ->false
>
> ab_c ->false
>
> a-b_c.->false
>
> a@-b_C. ->true
>
> .a-b_c. ->true

I tried  `/[^\w-\.]/` only ".a-b_c." was fail, I get false **(I hope be true)**
and I tried `/^\./` can be ".a-b_c." true, but other was fail.

has any body can help me?

Comment: "not start with ."? but the last one starts with a .

Comment: What I gather from your explanation and you test cases aren't matching up. You need a regex that has only word characters (letters, numbers, and underscores), dashes (-), or dots (.), but that doesn't start with a dot? Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to match string including only `\w`, `-` or `.` and not starting with `.`, then try this:

```
/^(?!\.)[\w.-]+$/
```

Details:

- `^` - search from start of string
- `(?!\.)` - don't match if there is `.` symbol at this position
- `[\w.-]+` - match to more than 1 symbols from `\w.-` set
- $ - match to end of string

Testing:

- `abc` -> **matched**
- `ab_c` -> **matched**
- `a-b_c.` -> **matched**
- `a@-b_C.` -> not matched
- `.a-b_c.` -> not matched

Comment: These "Testing" results appear to be the opposite of the OP's "hope the result is".

Comment: I don't understand what "true" or "false" means in OP's description. So I've used "matched" word instead. Any way you can inverse result of match if needed (`if (! matched)`).

Comment: It's work!thank you.
And I tried this /(^\.{1}?|[^\w-.])/ ,it's work too!
but I think your is better.

And sorry about my English .